# about hidden memory in android phone in miui 6 of mi4i?

Tags: applications

I have 11.5 gb of usable internal memory, out of which 1.3 gb is only usable, but after going inside the internal memory folder, I find files of only 5.58 gb. so the think I would like to know is where is my other 5 gb of data or why the other data isnt being shown?

Comment: Give us the output (screenshots) of [Diskinfo](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=me.kuder.diskinfo) and [DiskUsage](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.diskusage).

Answer (score 0):

Download [ES File Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop). Go to left pane > Tools > Memory scanner -- it will tell your directory structure and their sizes. Check *Show hidden files* option first.